# certificate in jks keystore to be imported in java home

Tags: java, import, keystore, pfx, jks

I have to develop a web app that makes calls to web services. 
I use Jdeveloper for this.
I have just a PFX file that I have imported in windows so I can view the WDSL of web service from a browser (Chrome in my case).
I get the jks keystore from PFX version using this 
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore original.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore generated.jks -deststoretype JKS .

Now I have to import this certificate some where in java_home (using keytool or maybe something else) to be used by jdeveloper wizards that access web services to authenticate to web services.

Many thanks,
Aurel

Answer (score 1):

Java comes with a default TrustStore which can be found here **%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts**. It is of type **JKS** and the password to it **changeit**. If you add the certificate to this file, it is trusted by Java. So be cautious in what Certificates you are trusting.

Answer (score 0):

I used keystore explorer to trasform the PFX type of keystore to JKS .

Then I used this store as truststore  for the client ws that is connecting to a self signed server
Thanks,
Aurel

Comment: It's good that you found the answer yourself, however I think if you would elaborate a bit more, future persons with a similar problem could profit more.